# Microservice - Docker - Kubernetes

Tags: docker, kubernetes, microservices

I have created docker container running on : http://localhost:8080/swagger/index.html

I have kubernetes pod running on : http://localhost:32729/swagger/index.html.

As of now i can access container directly using **http://localhost:8080/swagger/index.html**, however i want to restrict it. instead it can only accessible through kubernetes pod **http://localhost:32729/swagger/index.html.**

Thanks.

Comment: Can you [edit] the question to include a [mcve]?  "It's running on localhost" is almost meaningless as a statement; in between the Docker container network namespace, the Kubernetes Pod, and the system running the browser, there are at least three different "localhosts" in this question.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.